# Should questions that are useful and relevant on Mathematics SE be copied across to Operations Research SE?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, questions

By useful and relevant, I mean questions like [Operations research book to start with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/operations-research-book-to-start-with), [Introduction to Operations Research](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279369/introduction-to-operations-research), or even [How can I mathematically model and analyze an incremental game like Cookie Clicker?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065779/how-can-i-mathematically-model-and-analyze-an-incremental-game-like-cookie-click)

So I’m advocating for questions that are generalistic and particularly interesting on Mathematics SE to be made community-wiki on Operations Research SE. Questions that don’t fall into this category include specific mathematical questions or specific programming problems.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you proposing a community-wiki that is a *list of links* to posts like that, or *copying and pasting the content* of those posts?

Comment: Possibly relevant discussion from bioinformatics meta: https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22

Comment: @TheSimliFire: Can you migrate this question from CS to OR? At the time that I asked it, I didn't know about OR, but it only got 1 upvote and 0 answers in several months over there. I think it will do better in OR: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109039/max-cut-are-there-any-algorithms-or-codes-for-classical-computers-that-cater-t

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have encountered a problem in work or study, then certainly feel free to ask it your own words in the context of *this* site. But I would ***not*** suggest going around seeking out questions already asked and answered elsewhere as a way to pad out your content.

The purpose of *creating* this site is to expand the scope of questions which cannot already be asked elsewhere. Certainly some incidental overlap in scope is to be expected, but the goal of having your own site is to curate a collection of content unique to this community specifically; not to simply copy content from elsewhere.

I'm sure the folks will have plenty of questions on their own — you simply do not need other people's stuff to make this site work. When you copy a bit of text without any real engagement in asking or answering it yourself, you will lose that sense of ownership in what you are building here. Most people with access to this site will also have access to a Google search — **it's just not a great way to start a new site.**

Answer (score 2):

A difference about the [bioinformatics comment](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/should-questions-that-are-useful-and-relevant-on-mathematics-se-be-copied-across#comment81_74) Larry made on the question here was partially [answered in a comment](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/migrating-bioinformatics-questions-from-other-se-sites/22#comment40_14) there, and again by the (former) moderator in an [answer](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22/4179) - that was about migrating, which isn't possible for older questions.

Generally speaking sites like to keep their popular Q&A's and the interest they generate.

OTOH, if you spot a *good* question (regardless of upvotes) that is old and has no answers (or any answers that have been poorly received) it is polite and helpful to **write a comment on the question** on the other site informing the OP that our new site would welcome their question here (especially if ***you*** are willing to answer it here). It's better to get credit for an original answer here than to take (or wiki away) credit for a question from another site.

The OP gets credit for their question and hopefully a better answer, while some of us gets credit for answering. Be certain to remind them to use the share link and edit their question on the other site with a link to their question here (and vice versa).

This is helpful for old questions without suitable answers and questions that were closed as off-topic on the other site (as long as they are on-topic here). Don't do it to new questions, as such actions won't be appreciated (it's poaching).

Comment: Great, thanks for your advice.