# Is this page coordinated at all with OR-Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I know there's another Operations Research StackExchange like site: https://www.or-exchange.org

Do we know how this site will differ from that? Is that considered a related effort/are there ways to transfer users between the two?

Is that considered a competing effort? Are there fundamental flaws in that page that are addressed here? etc..

### Notes:

After doing some research it appears that OR-exchange is now shut down and insisting users migrate to here, so these are coordinated efforts.

That now has me curious if there could be a way to migrate all the questions answers and comments from OR Exchange into OR Beta.

Comment: Similar Q&A, about [copy from other site](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/74/51). No.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you noted, OR-Exchange is now shut down, due to over-spamming. In fact, it was the non-existence of OR-Exchange that prompted the creation of OR.SE.

There has been some [discussion about migrating questions from OR-Exchange](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/73/38). The general idea is that if there are interesting and useful questions on OR-X, there's no reason not to ask/answer them here. But it would not be a good idea to "migrate" in a wholesale way.

Comment: Interesting, but I am wondering why OR-Ex is over-spammed but stack-exchange sites are not!

Comment: @Opt because SE sites have much more robust anti-spam defenses (including some really excellent moderators) ;)